# Should we rename [spaceflight] to [space-travel]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

While looking at [my own answer](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3947/29) to [Space flight vs space ships?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3937/29), and specifically the bullet list at the top,

> - *Spaceflight* is about the **process**
> - *Spaceships* is about the **technology**

...I was struck by a thought.

Given the similarity in naming of the two tags, which apparently is contributing to some confusion, it might be easier to tell the difference between the two if we rename [spaceflight](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceflight) (the process) to [space-travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-travel) (possibly adding spaceflight back as a  synonym) and keep [spaceships](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceships) the same (possibly adding a synonym [spacecraft](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacecraft) because that is a well established term in the industry).

It would seem to pretty well match the current tag wiki, which says in the excerpt that [spaceflight](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceflight) is...

> For questions about the process of travelling through space, including in orbit around a planet or moon.

**Opinions on this?**

Comment: yes sir as flight is defined as the action or process of flying through the **air** such as the Challenger disaster or the likes.

Comment: Voyager I strikes me as a fine example of spaceflight.  Not so much with space-travel.

Comment: @HDE226868 travel means having destination(probably means more interstellar flight), when destination it is no important, but more concerned about difficulties of .... Travel seems to me more confusing, as it have distinct tourism color.

Comment: Okay, I did the rename. I tried it last week, but because [tag:space-travel] was already a synonym of [tag:spaceflight], I used the `swap` option, which broke something. A CM got it that reversed, so today I canceled the synonym, renamed [tag:spaceflight] to [tag:space-travel], then added [tag:spaceflight] as a synonym. I'm reasonably certain it worked this time.

Answer (score -1):

Aren't spaceflight and spaceships all part of the same complex, and questions about one cannot be answered without considerations of the other?

You cannot reasonably answer questions about interstellar travel without considering the mode of transportation. And you cannot answer questions about spaceships (or other modes of interstellar travel) without considering their purpose, transportation.

In the context of worldbuilding, one tag is sufficient to encompass spaceships, space-travel, and spaceflight, as well as non-vehicular transportation such as beaming and wormholes. I would call that tag [transportation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation).

[Transportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport) includes everything that surrounds the movement of people and goods from one location to another, including but not limited to politics, technology, infrastructure, vehicles, or energy.

Comment: It is perfectly possible for a question to be about, for example, the process of constructing a spacecraft. Such a question would benefit from knowledge of spacecrafts, but might not require knowledge of space travel. Also note that spacecraft can be used in orbit around a single celestial body; they are not restricted to transfers between different bodies.

Comment: The construction of a satellite requires knowledge (and planning) of how it is *transported* into orbit and how it is *transported* along in orbit. The form and function of a satellite are dependend on the mode of transporting it into space as well as the circular path of its orbit.

Comment: @what it is possible to merge, if there is need to do so, but we absolutely do not have to. I have model of spaceship, pretty complex one, would I ask or answer travel itself would be not important part of that q/a. If one wish to have some capabilities of satellite in first place, difficulties of transporting could be solved by plot/magic.  Two distinct approaches where craft defines travel, and when travel defines craft - as we do not have complex solutions, it makes perfect sense to define which one is more important for OP.